# About query cache in RDS mysql 8.0

Tags: amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, blue-green-deployment

Recently we changed version of RDS mysql from 5.7 to 8.0 by using blue/green deployment. first we put our green instance in 5.7 version later we upgraded the instance and switched over successfully.Later problem got started. CPU utilization is 90% above now and application database running is very slow. and there is no query cache in mysql 8.0..can you please explain how to over come these 2 problrms..please

We tried changing instance type of RDS from t2.medium to t3.medium. still showing 90% of CPU utilization(before it never touches 90%).and also added inno db buffer to database still there database is very slow..I want to resolve these two problems as soon as possible.I need solutions for these two Issues

Comment: Are the 2 problems, A) no query cache in 8.0 and B) 90% CPU utilization?  Please confirm.

Comment: For your B) Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide CPU conserving suggestions.

Comment: Could you post the CPU utilization graph for the last 7 days?

Comment: For your A) observation, we have encouaged customers on 5.7 to TURN OFF query feature and none of them missed the query cache feature for the past two years.  The reason they do not miss the Query Cache feature is because the processing to manage qcache_lowmem_prunes can be very resource intensive.  This reinforces the need to use the Slow Query Log to minimize the number of queries running more than one second.  A goal since the beginning of serious computing.

Comment: If you must have Query Cache, MariaDB still supports Query Cache.  I suspect you want to avoid changing from MySQL, if possible.  Not a trivial project.